# Write at specific position at a file with open()

Tags: c++, c, file-descriptor

Hello I am trying to simulate two programs that send and receive files in C++ from the network, something like client and server. To begin with I have to split a file to pages of 4096 bytes and send it to the other program in order to create the file. The way I send and receive files through the network is by write and read. So in the client programm I must create a function tha receives the packages and puts them into a file. I cannot figure a way to put the packages in to the file. For example I a file has 2 pages I must create another file using these 2 pages. Also i cannot know if they come in order so I must create the file and put them in the right position.

```
/*consider the connections are ok and the file's name is at char* name*/

int file=open(name,"O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0666);
char buffer[4096];
int pagenumber;
for(int i=0;i<page_number;i++){
  read(socket,&pagenumber,sizeof(int));
  read(socket,buffer,sizeof(int));
  write(file(pagenumber*4096),buffer,4096);
}
```

This code works for pagenumber=0 but for pagenumber=1 nothing happens! Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Added two missing ';' and 2 ')'... that probably wasn't the problem

Comment: `write(file(pagenumber*4096),buffer,4096);` ?? What is `file(pagenumber*4096)`?

Comment: I didn't really meant it but it was the only way to help you understand the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write at a certain position in the file you must use lseek

```
 off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);
```

It takes the descriptor, the offset and the final parameter is a constant in these:

> SEEK_SET The offset is set to offset bytes.
>
> SEEK_CUR The offset is set to its current location plus offset bytes.
>
> SEEK_END The offset is set to the size of the file plus offset bytes.

If you know how big is the file going to be, you can use ftruncate for it.

```
int ftruncate(int fd, off_t length);
```

Anyway even if you create a file that is huge, since most filesystems on Linux support sparse files, the actual file on disk will be the sum of the blocks that have been written.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `write()` is a filedescriptor, which you optained with `open()`. So it should be

```
int file = open(...);
...
write(file,buffer,4096);
```

not

```
write(file(pagenumber*4096),buffer,4096);
```

Regarding the question as to how to write at a specific position. You can prepare the file beforehand with write, and then use `seek()` to position the file where you want to write at. For a description of seek you can [look here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lseek).

Answer (score 0):

Mario, first of all, lets no rely on garbage in 'pagenumber' to continue the loop (which is happening when loop boundary condition is checked here for the first time). Now, if you are writing page number '0' and then page following it, pagenumber will be initialized to 0 and your loop will come out. Also, please check bytes written and read in write and read system calls respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your notifications I will change it! you are right!

Answer (score 0):

try [pwrite](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite)

```
int file=open(name,"O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0666);
char buffer[4096];
int pagenumber;
for(int i=0;i<page_number;i++){
  read(socket,&pagenumber,sizeof(int));
  read(socket,buffer,sizeof(int));
  pwrite(file,buffer,4096,4096*i);
}
```